# Lightning PickList with Image and text

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

How to display the image in lightning picklist?

```
<lightning:select name="select1" label="Choose your item?" required="true" value="{!v.optionval}">
                        <option text="choose one..." value=""></option>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.option.value}" var="opt" indexVar="sfIndex">
                            <option value="{!opt.name}"><img src="{!opt.icon.url}"/></option>
                        </aura:iteration>
 </lightning:select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component doesn't support icons. Consider implementing a custom [lookup](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/) component instead.